# Strange Behavior: Fixnum value does not match Numeric in case ... when

Tags: ruby, case, numeric

I have a piece of code that looks like:

```
case n
when Numeric
  (do this)
else
  (do that)
end
```

but it is executing "(do that)" when n is a Fixnum.  I set a breakpoint at the (do that) and did "pp n.class" producing output of "Fixnum".  I also tried "pp Numeric === n" which produced "false", and "pp Numeric === 5", producing "true".  How can n be reporting a class of Fixnum and yet fail the test "Numeric === n"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your `n` is indeed a `Fixnum`?

```
>> n = 5 #=> 5
>> case n
..   when Numeric
..     "Numeric"
..   else
..     "Not numeric"
..   end #=> "Numeric"
```

Just asking cause you also mentioned that `Numeric === n` returned false, which it shouldn't:

```
>> n = 5 #=> 5
>> Numeric === n #=> true
```

Can you maybe post a somewhat bigger snippet of code or something (I know you said that `n.class` is `Fixnum`, but the code certainly doesn't behave that way).

Comment: but `>> n === Numeric #=> false` why is it so odd?

Comment: @nash Probably because Class#=== and Object#=== are different methods.

Comment: @nash When `Numeric` is on the left side then `Module#===` is used, which returns `true` if the right hand side is a descendant of the module. When a number is on the left side then `Fixnum#===` is used, which returns `true` if the right hand side is numerically equal to the left.

Comment: I am as sure as I can be.  "pp n.class" gives "Fixnum". "pp Numeric === n" gives "false"; "pp Numeric === 5" gives "true"; "pp Numeric === n.to_i" gives "true".  Very strange!

Comment: I'm going to guess (since I had a similar problem with array vs. association pseudo-array) that my argument is not really a Fixnum, but something else masquerading as a Fixnum.  Consider this closed.